# Changing object parameter with event handler

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an object and add it to an array I created as a parameter GUI object I constructed. For some reason I keep getting ***TheDates cannot be resolved to a Variable***.

Object being constructed:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DateDriver myDateFrame = new DateDriver();
}

//Constructor
public DateDriver()
{
    outputFrame = new JFrame();
    outputFrame.setSize(600, 500);
    outputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    String command;
    Date [] theDates = new Date[100];    //this is the array I am having issues with
    int month, day, year;

    ...
}
```

This is where my problem with theDates is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{    //The meat and Potatoes
     if ( e.getSource() == arg3Ctor) 
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "3 arg Constructor got it");
        int month = Integer.parseInt(monthField.getText());
        int day = Integer.parseInt(dayField.getText());
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
        theDates[getIndex()] = new Date(month, day, year);//here is the actual issue
     }
}
```

I don't know if I'm over thinking it or what, I've tried making the array *static, public*, etc. I've also tried implementing it as `myDayeFrame.theDates`.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a scope issue. theDates was declared in the constructor and is visible only in the constructor. A possible solution: declare it as a class field. Sure initialize it in the constructor, but if it is declared in the class, it is visible in the class.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate the help, I never thought about initializing the parameters as a class field. I was doing this for the buttons but it just didn't click for me. Thank you very much, I will provide this tip to my class mates that are having the same issue.

Comment: @Dustin: glad we could help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `theDates` as local variable in the constructor, thus its scope is limited within the constructor. Instead, declare it as a field of the class:

```
private Data[] theDates;

// ...

   public DateDriver()
   {
       theDates = new Date[100];
       // ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You have defined **theDates**, which is an Array Object Reference Variable inside the Constructor, so its having its scope inside the Constructor itself.

**2.** You should declare the **theDates at the class scope**, so it will be visible throughout inside that class.

**3.** And it will be better if you use Collection instead of Array, go for ArrayList

**Eg:**

```
public class DateDriver {

    private ArrayList<Date> theDates;

    public DateDriver() {
        theDates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could use an ArrayList but the teacher is very strict with what he wants. I appreciate the input, you were very clear and concise.